# Cannot see any functions in gdb

Tags: android, c, linux, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to debug a very simple C program running in Android ARM environment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    printf ("%d, sleeping for 10\n", getpid());
    sleep (10);
    printf ("%d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot /Application/Binaries/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/ printf.c -o printf
```

I launched that application and started gdbserver in the emulator, and attached locally.

Now I if I try to break on something:

```
(gdb) b 
_DYNAMIC               __FINI_ARRAY__         __bss_start            _end                   atexit
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_  __INIT_ARRAY__         __dso_handle           _start                 main
__CTOR_LIST__          __PREINIT_ARRAY__      _edata                 abitag                 
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
                        No          /system/bin/linker
                        No          libc.so
```

No functions is visible. And libc.so seems like not loaded? That's totally weird.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Add a few parameters:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot /Application/Binaries/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/ printf.c -o printf -g -Wall
```

And now:

```
(gdb) b 
/Application/Binaries/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm//usr/include/unistd.h
_DYNAMIC
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
__CTOR_LIST__
__FINI_ARRAY__
__INIT_ARRAY__
__PREINIT_ARRAY__
__bss_start
__dso_handle
__page_shift
__page_size
_edata
_end
_start
abitag
atexit
char
double
float
int
long int
long long int
long long unsigned int
long unsigned int
main
printf.c
short int
short unsigned int
signed char
unsigned char
unsigned int
```

Comment: Show your exact [cross-]compilation command.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile with `-Wall -g` flags to your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) cross-compiler for ARM.

Shared libraries (including `libc.so`) get loaded once the program is runnning. Try to put a breakpoint in `main`, and only there do the `info sharedlibrary` thing.

Comment: main() is already running, I attached the process when I saw the output of the first printf

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty common symptom with native apps/.so built without "-O0 -g" option.

Looks like you are building pure native apps that use C/C++ run time that come with AOSP.

The way you are building works fine as long as you are maintaining your own build system. Once you start using the Android.mk builds, it is not that straight forward controlling debug flags.

Please check [Debugging native applications of Android using eclipse](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html) article if you are planning to do lot of native development in AOSP.